# How can I disable emacs delete-selection-mode

Tags: emacs, overwrite

Emacs's Delete-selection-mode, modern as it feels, makes it too easy to inadvertently delete code. Thus, I would like it disabled by default. Therefore, I added

```
(delete-selection-mode f)
```

to my init.el file but that had no effect. By which I mean, if I highlight a region and type something, the contents of the selection are replaced with the new typing. I also tried toggling the mode with `M-x delete-selection-mode` command, but that had no effect. I use Emacs 24.1.1 on Windows7, Mac and Linux.   What am I missing, is there some other mode or variable that I should be enabling instead?

Comment: Try customizing with `M-x customize` if you're not very familiar with Emacs Lisp.

Comment: I don't think that `delete-selection-mode` is enabled by default, which means somewhere along the way you added it -- e.g., by installing a third-party library that enables it.  In general, minor modes are enabled with a positive integer and disabled with a negative integer -- e.g., `(name-of-minor-mode -1)` to disable and `(name-of-minor-mode 1)` to enable.  Before disabling it, you should look really hard to find out where it got enabled and then remove or comment out that line of code.

Comment: Update: It turns out that enabling CUA mode enables delete selection behavior. I'm going to investigate that further.

Comment: I needed to add `(cua-delete-selection nil)`. Thanks for the tip, lawlist.

Comment: Post the answer as an answer, and accept it. That way, this question will not show up in the unanswered list.

Comment: Bats: Note that although `t` is the canonical lisp symbol for 'true', it is **not** the case that `f` means 'false'! `nil` is the only 'false' value, and *all* non-nil values (including `f`, if it were bound to a non-nil value) are considered to be 'true'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete-selection-mode` is set by default when CUA mode is enabled, but it can be disabled via `M-x customize`. CUA settings are a subgroup of the "Editing Basics" subgroup of the top-level "Editing" group.  To disable delete-selection mode, use the Value Menu of the "Cua Delete Selection" item and change the setting to Disabled.  This will place the following line among the custom-set-variables defined in your .emacs or init.el file:  `(cua-delete-selection nil)`.  After this has been set, actions such as cut with `C-w` or pressing the delete key will continue to operate normally on regions.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. My .emacs file calls "(delete-selection-mode nil)" and sets "(cua-delete-selection nil)" but I have the same very annoying behavior. I don't mind it when the selection is visible, but I typically turn off transient-mode, and want backspace and ctrl-d to operate on one char (if no arg given) while leaving point, and all the other characters between point and mark, untouched. I tried (customize), but it didn't work either.  This is on OSX, by the way.